# Difference between count of subqueried group by and distinct on group by columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, distinct

Is there a potential for different results in these two queries? Is there one that's preferred?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id, b.id) AS `count`
  FROM a
  JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
```

vs.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`
  FROM (SELECT TRUE
          FROM a
          JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
         GROUP BY a.id, b.id) g
```

To me it seems like the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` would be preferred because you're not dealing with a subquery. I just don't know if there are any gotchas. maybe something to do with nulls?

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I'm asking specifically about MySQL for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two return different values (at least when there is one column).

`count(distinct)` ignores `NULL` values.  So, `count(distinct NULL)` returns `0` not `1`.

`group by` includes `NULL` values as a separate row, so they are included in that query.

[This](http://rextester.com/XLHRRH91840) rextester illustrates the difference for one column.

[This](http://rextester.com/WRCHO60682) rextester illustrates the difference for two columns.

Comment: So if guaranteed that the id's returned were never null would they then be the same? And would the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` be any more efficient?

Comment: @Will . . . The results should be the same.  I could imagine some situation with string collations where the values might be compared differently (I'm not saying this happens, just a remote possibility).  The performance of the two should be comparable, although I have seen situations where either version is faster (on different databases).  It depends on the optimizer.